# How to unit test PHP traits

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, traits

I want to know if there is a solution on how to unit-test a PHP trait.

I know we can test a class which is using the trait, but I was wondering if there are better approaches.

Thanks for any advice in advance :)

**EDIT**

One alternative is to use the Trait in the test class itself as I'm going to demonstrate bellow.

**But** I'm not that keen on this approach since there is no guaranty there are no similar method names between the trait, the class and also the `PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase` (in this example):

Here is an example trait:

```
trait IndexableTrait
{
    /** @var int */
    private $index;

    /**
     * @param $index
     * @return $this
     * @throw \InvalidArgumentException
     */
    public function setIndex($index)
    {
        if (false === filter_var($index, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException('$index must be integer.');
        }

        $this->index = $index;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return int|null
     */
    public function getIndex()
    {
        return $this->index;
    }
}
```

and its test:

```
class TheAboveTraitTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    use TheAboveTrait;

    public function test_indexSetterAndGetter()
    {
        $this->setIndex(123);
        $this->assertEquals(123, $this->getIndex());
    }

    public function test_indexIntValidation()
    {
        $this->setExpectedException(\Exception::class, '$index must be integer.');
        $this->setIndex('bad index');
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide code you've tried to do this with which does not work. That'll help someone assist you.

Comment: @AdamB, I wrote the [first answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31083193/4960774) myself, which has a sample code. but please note its not like something is broken or not working, i just want to know if there are any good methods to unit test traits directly and not indirectly by unit testing a class which uses that trait. tanks

Answer (score 109, accepted):

You can test a Trait using a similar to testing an Abstract Class' concrete methods.

[PHPUnit has a method getMockForTrait](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/9.1/test-doubles.html?highlight=trait#mocking-traits-and-abstract-classes) which will return an object that uses the trait.  Then you can test the traits functions.

Here is the example from the documentation:

```
<?php
trait AbstractTrait
{
    public function concreteMethod()
    {
        return $this->abstractMethod();
    }

    public abstract function abstractMethod();
}

class TraitClassTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testConcreteMethod()
    {
        $mock = $this->getMockForTrait('AbstractTrait');

        $mock->expects($this->any())
             ->method('abstractMethod')
             ->will($this->returnValue(TRUE));

        $this->assertTrue($mock->concreteMethod());
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 15):

Since PHP 7 we can now use annonymous classes...

```php
$class = new class {
    use TheTraitToTest;
};

// We now have everything available to test using $class
```

Answer (score 11):

You can also use `getObjectForTrait` , then assert the actual result if you want.

```
class YourTraitTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testGetQueueConfigFactoryWillCreateConfig()
    {
        $obj = $this->getObjectForTrait(YourTrait::class);

        $config = $obj->getQueueConfigFactory();

        $this->assertInstanceOf(QueueConfigFactory::class, $config);
    }

    public function testGetQueueServiceWithoutInstanceWillCreateConfig()
    {
        $obj = $this->getObjectForTrait(YourTrait::class);

        $service = $obj->getQueueService();

        $this->assertInstanceOf(QueueService::class, $service);
    }
}
```