# Can dynamically add trait in object?

Tags: php, laravel, reflection

I want to dynamically add/set a Trait in object. How can I do it?

For example i have `$object`;

```php
$object->setTrait($someTrait);
```

Thanks for help.

**Edit**

```php
<?php

namespace GamApi\Models\Traits;

use GamApi\Scopes\OrganizationScope;

/**
 *
 * Trait BelongsToOrganizationTrait
 * @package GamApi\Models\Traits
 */
trait BootOrganization
{
    /**
     * For saving resource auto-complete organization_id attribute
     * Add global OrganizationScope
     *
     */
    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        // global organization_id scope
        static::addGlobalScope(new OrganizationScope());

        // set organization_id for saving
        static::creating(function ($model){
            if (defined('ORGANIZATION_ID')) {
                $model->organization_id = ORGANIZATION_ID;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I want to test this class, and I think that I can make `$object` then dynamically `insert Trait to the object` and then test `Trait boot` method.

Comment: Can you explain why you'd need this?  Sounds like an XY problem.

Comment: Duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/q/10461965/296555 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/14355029/296555

Comment: If it's for testing only,  you might want to look into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31083192/how-to-unit-test-php-traits/31124840